# Query about usage of setattr() in Python-Redmine

Tags: python, redmine, python-redmine

`setattr()` for an item in Redmine issues, is failing, with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test\get_redmine_data.py", line 47, in <module>
    print (item.assigned_to)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\resources\standard.py", line 150, in __getattr__
    return super(Issue, self).__getattr__(attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\resources\base.py", line 164, in __getattr__
    attr, encoded = self.encode(attr, decoded, self.manager)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\resources\base.py", line 266, in encode
    return attr, manager.new_manager(cls._resource_map[attr]).to_resource(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\managers\base.py", line 29, in to_resource
    return self.resource_class(self, resource)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\resources\base.py", line 130, in __init__
    self._decoded_attrs = dict(dict.fromkeys(relations_includes), **attributes)
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

I am trying to set some default assignee, for issues where the assignee is not set. The code fails at the line, where I print the attribute I just set. My code is given below:

```
redmine = Redmine('http://redmine_url', username='uname', password='pwd')
project = redmine.project.get('proj_name')
work_items = project.issues
for item in work_items:
   assignee_not_set = getattr(item,'assigned_to',True)
   if assignee_not_set == True:
       print item.id
       setattr(item,'assigned_to','Deepak')
       print (item.assigned_to)
```

I also tried using the update() method,

```
redmine.project.update(item.id, assigned_to='Deepak')
```

That also fails with another error - `redminelib.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Requested resource doesn't exist`.
I verifed that the issue id exists in Redmine.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - which line fails, with what traceback?

Comment: Hello jonrsharpe, I updated the question for more clarity. I would not be able to share the Redmine URL and such stuff, though.

Comment: Also before you start doing something, check first if there is a plugin for that... https://github.com/ozguryazilimas/redmine_default_assignee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. The attribute name is `assigned_to_id` and not `assigned_to`
2. It accepts user id which is `int` and not a username which is `str`
3. No need to use `setattr()` here, just use `item.assigned_to_id = 123`
4. You need to call `item.save()` after setting `assigned_to_id` otherwise it won't be saved to Redmine
5. When you're trying to use `update()` method, you're using in on a `Project` resource and not on `Issue` resource, this is why you're getting `ResourceNotFoundError`

All this information is available in the docs: https://python-redmine.com/resources/issue.html

Comment: Thanks Max Tepkeev. Yeah, I should have paid more attention to the documentation.